# how to pass props from flatlist to search?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-props

I have my Main function in one file:

```
import Search from '../Components/Header';
function Main() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Search />
      <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            style={{borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
          />
    </View>
```

And Search class in another file:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Data",
  }
];

const Item = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />;

export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: DATA,
      error: null,
      searchValue: "",
    };
    this.arrayholder = DATA;
  };  
  searchFunction = (text) => {
    const updatedData = this.arrayholder.filter((item) => {
      const item_data = `${item.title.toUpperCase()})`;
      const text_data = text.toUpperCase();
      return item_data.indexOf(text_data) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({ data: updatedData, searchValue: text });
  }; 
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={Headerstyles.rectangle}>
          <SearchBar
            value={this.state.searchValue}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.searchFunction(text)}          
          />          
        </View>      
    );
  }
}
```

So as I understand I should pass props from Flatlist to Search class, but I get an error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. I think it's not only about data and also renderItem  and keyExtractor.
How can I do this?

Comment: you can keep a state variable in the Main function and can pass it as a prop to the search function

Comment: As the above comments mentions, it would be easier to have your data and render function in Main component and pass down those props to search and flatlist. If your flatlist renders items based on search result then it would be easier to have Flatlist as a child of Search component and you can pass the search result down to flatlist child.

In react, data typically flows from parent to child via props. Here is a [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-4) to help you decide where to keep your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component `Main` does not contain a state called `data`. This state is defined in `Search`. I would create the state inside `Main` and pass the setter function to `Search`.

```js
function Main() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(DATA);

    return (
        <View>
            <Search setData={setData} />
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                style={{borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Then, use the new props in `Search` as follows.

```js
export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      searchValue: "",
    };
    this.arrayholder = DATA;
  };  
  searchFunction = (text) => {
    const updatedData = this.arrayholder.filter((item) => {
      const item_data = `${item.title.toUpperCase()})`;
      const text_data = text.toUpperCase();
      return item_data.indexOf(text_data) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({ searchValue: text });
    this.props.setData(updatedData);
  }; 
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={Headerstyles.rectangle}>
          <SearchBar
            value={this.state.searchValue}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.searchFunction(text)}          
          />          
        </View>      
    );
  }
}
```